# Generating ellipse with rotation and semi-major and semi-minor axes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ellipsis

I have the parameters of an eclipse: semi-major axis; semi-minor axis; rotation angle; x-position of the centre of the ellipse; y-position of the centre of the ellipse.

I wish to produce an array whereby all points inside the ellipse are set to one and all points outside are zero.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25051105/6267719), which gave a solution to this *without rotation*, and *using height and width*, rather than semi-major and semi-minor:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x0 = 4  # x center,
a = 5  #  half width
y0 = 2  # y center,
b = 3  # half height
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)  # x values of interest
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)[:,
                            None]  # y values of interest, as a "column" array
ellipse = ((x - x0) / a)**2 + (
    (y - y0) / b)**2 <= 1  # True for points inside the ellipse

plt.imshow(ellipse, origin="lower")  # Plot
```

[image: non-rotated ellipse]

Thus, I'm looking to modify this code to take the parameters I require.  I found a definition of the general equation of an eclipse [here](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/joma/Volume8/Kalman/General.html)

[image]

I attempted to reproduce this with this modification:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x0 = 4  # x center,
a = 5  #  half width
y0 = 2  # y center,
b = 3  # half height
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)  # x values of interest
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)[:,
                            None]  # y values of interest, as a "column" array

def calc_ellipse(x, y, x_centre, y_centre, rotation, semi_major, semi_minor):
    # https://www.maa.org/external_archive/joma/Volume8/Kalman/General.html
    ...
    term1 = ((x - x_centre) * np.cos(rotation)) + (
        (y - y0) * np.sin(rotation))**2
    term2 = ((x - x_centre) * np.sin(rotation)) + (
        (y - y0) * np.cos(rotation))**2
    ellipse = ((term1 / semi_major**2) + (term2 / semi_minor**2)) <= 1
    return ellipse


ellipse = calc_ellipse(x, y, x0, y0, 0, a, b)

plt.imshow(ellipse, origin="lower")  # Plot
```

[image]

However as you can see I end up with a strange shape, even when I set the rotation angle to 0.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59735611/6267719) showed a way of generating an ellipse with a rotation, however the parameters are hard-coded, and thus is not reuseable or easy to interpret.

How would I generate an array like this with the parameters defining the general equation of the eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `calc_ellipse` function you are missing parenthesis in `term1` and `term2`. To match the formula you've posted it should look like this:

```
    term1 = (((x - x_centre) * np.cos(rotation)) + (
        (y - y0) * np.sin(rotation)))**2
    term2 = (((x - x_centre) * np.sin(rotation)) + (
        (y - y0) * np.cos(rotation)))**2
```

Or like this:

```
    term1 = ((x - x_centre) * np.cos(rotation) + 
        (y - y0) * np.sin(rotation))**2
    term2 = ((x - x_centre) * np.sin(rotation) + 
        (y - y0) * np.cos(rotation))**2
```

Try those changes and see if it works.

Comment: Many thanks, this looks like the right answer for me.  I note that for my use case, I had to adjust the linear space so that it was 1 per unit for the values I had to make sense: `x = np.linspace(0, 512, 512)`

Answer (score 0):

Also you've copied the +/- signs wrong.
It should be:

```
term1 = (((x - x_centre) * np.cos(rotation) + 
        (y - y_centre) * np.sin(rotation)))**2
term2 = (((x - x_centre) * np.sin(rotation) -
        (y - y_centre) * np.cos(rotation)))**2
```

according to what you've posted